# sometimes i get invalid csrf token with multipart forms

Tags: node.js, express, upload, csrf, formidable

i am using expressjs 4 with csurf and formidable, sometimes i when i use a multipart form to upload:

> Error: invalid csrf token
>       at createToken (/Users/mecha/projects/sherka/maktabi/node_modules/csurf/index.js:94:19)
>       at Layer.handle (/Users/mecha/projects/sherka/maktabi/node_modules/csurf/index.js:59:24)
>       at trim_prefix (/Users/mecha/projects/sherka/maktabi/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:240:15)
>       at /Users/mecha/projects/sherka/maktabi/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:208:9
>       at Function.proto.process_params (/Users/mecha/projects/sherka/maktabi/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:269:12)
>       at next (/Users/mecha/projects/sherka/maktabi/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:199:19)
>       at /Users/mecha/projects/sherka/maktabi/node_modules/express-session/index.js:226:9
>       at Object._onImmediate (/Users/mecha/projects/sherka/maktabi/node_modules/express-session/session/memory.js:58:9)
>       at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:330:15)

but sometimes it just works fine without any errors, any idea what is it i am doing wrong ?

here is my code

```
app.use(function(req, res, next){
    res.locals.session = req.session;
    res.locals.messages = req.flash('success');
    res.locals.errors = req.flash('error');
    res.locals.csrftoken = req.csrfToken();
    next();
});
```

here is an html form

```
<form id="new_desk_form" class="form" method="post" action="/space/{{ space.id}}/add/desk?_csrf={{ csrftoken }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

here is the route handler

```
app.post('/space/:id/add/desk', helpers.ensureAuth, function(req, res){
    var id = req.params.id;
    var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
    form.uploadDir = __dirname+'/../public/uploads/spaces/'+id;
    form.keepExtensions = true;
    form.encoding = 'utf-8';
    form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
            res.render('505.html')
        }
        var name = files.photo1.path.split('/');
        name = name[name.length-1];
        var pathToStore = "/uploads/spaces/"+id+'/'+name;
        var workspace = {};
        workspace.title = req.body.title;
        workspace.type = 'desk';
        workspace.photos = [];
        workspace.photos.push(pathToStore);
        workspace.currency = req.body.currency;
        workspace.quantity = req.body.quantity;
        workspace.prices = {};
        if(req.body.hourly){
            workspace.prices.hourly = req.body.hourly;
        }
        if(req.body.daily){
            workspace.prices.daily = req.body.daily;
        }
        if(req.body.monthly){
            workspace.prices.monthly = req.body.monthly;
        }
        Space.findOne({_id: id}, {}, function(err, space){
            if(err){
                console.log(err);
                    res.render('505.html');
            }
            space.workspaces.push(workspace);
            space.save(function(){
                res.redirect('/edit/'+req.id);
            })
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem you're having is an encoding issue. When the CSRF token fails to validate, it is most likely due to the CSRF token having a forward slash `/` or other character that needs to be encoded properly in a URL query string. This encoding is different from the escaping done by handlebars for variables with the two curly braces.

I would recommend using a hidden input instead, the browser should then encode it properly when the form is submitted:

`<input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="{{ csrftoken }}">`

Alternatively, you could also make sure that `csrftoken` is run through [encodeURIComponent()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) before being included in the `action` attribute of the form. You'd probably want to do this with a handlebars helper, which I believe you will need a third-party helper to do, here is one option: [handlebars-helpers](https://github.com/diy/handlebars-helpers#encodeuricomponent)

Comment: i already have a hidden input but it has the same error as the query string, i am using the query string as a second option. will try the encodeURIComponent though.

Comment: the hidden input works fine in normal cases but when it comes to a multipart form it doesn't, i am trying url encoding on the query string and seems like it works fine.

Comment: my problem was because I am using a multipart form (for uploading files). Moving the csrfToken from the hidden input to a URL query solved my problem.